# Can I skip specific file from "**/*.xml" rule in jenkins?

Tags: regular-expression, filenames, jenkins

So, the requirement is, consider all `.xml` files(which is the original pattern) except one specific file(example: `test/special.xml`)

Comment: in what situation? in a shell glob? which shell? a `find` expression?

Comment: @JeffSchaller to give more context,  I am using it in jenkins, JUnitResultsArchiver. which would be this field: https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/junit/JUnitResultArchiver.java#L70 .  The step looks something like this: ```step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testDataPublishers: [[$class: 'AttachmentPublisher']], testResults: '**/*.xml'])```

Answer (score 0):

The `**/*.xml` glob is (initially) a `zsh` feature. Assuming your *jenkins* calls `zsh` to expand that glob, and assuming you can ensure its `extendedglob` option is set, the syntax would be:

```
**/*.xml~test/special.xml
```

`~` above is a *except* glob operator only enabled when the `extendedglob` option is on.

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ echo **/*.xml
foo/a.xml foo/bar/b.xml test/special.xml
$ echo **/*.xml~test/special.xml
foo/a.xml foo/bar/b.xml
```